# What is "SVC-SEMPOST" error in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

MarkLogic is running on Linux (ubuntu) Machine.

Sometimes we are getting the below error

```
Error: Semaphore::post: SVC-SEMPOST: Semaphore post error: sem_post: Invalid argument
```

The error is intermittent.

I searched google a lot but could not find the reason behind this issue hence the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error would be better looked at from Marklogic support. There are a number of things that could happen with it and would require an investigation of your error logs and system setup.

The error normally happens when you have resource issues (http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post). Whats really happening is the pointer passed in that no longest exists. There is a knowledge base article about it from marklogic support. Its for windows but it could help (https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/195/0/troubleshooting-windows-file-system-errors-on-marklogic-server)